# How to re-ask for user input if user inputted a non-integer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, while-loop, integer

in part of one program i wanted to ensure that user inputs only
so i used:

```
num=int(raw_input())
while type(num)!= int:
   num=int(raw_input('You must enter number only'))
print num
```

But by doing this , **if the user inputted some non-integer like strings or anything else the whole code is displayed error.**
so how can i **make user re-enter the value until they input an integer**.

*the output was like*:

```
input your number
hdhe
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4b5e9a275ca4> in <module>()
      1 print'input your number'
----> 2 num=int(raw_input())
      3 while type(num)!= int:
      4     num=int(raw_input('You must enter number only'))
      5 print num

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hdhe'
```

Comment: Just delete the `int()` when defining `num` : `num = raw_input()`

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('input your number : '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('You entered a non integer value, try again.')
        continue

print('yay!! you gave the correct value as int')
```

Now you can do any cosmetic changes as you please.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your num = int(raw_input())  has already ensured it must  be an int and would raise ValueError if not int. So your while loop never gets to execute because it'll never get a non-int variable for num. Instead remove int() from the num variable and your good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You cast the input from the user directly to `int` on line 2. If this is not an integer a ValueError exception is thrown. We can modify your implementation and catch the exception when this happens, only exiting the loop when no exception occurs and num is an integer.

```
while True:
    num=raw_input()
    try:
        num=int(num)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Input is not an integer!"
print num
```

You might also be able to use a *regular expression* to check if the input value is an integer, or some other library function that checks whether the string from raw_input() is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance` to check whether the input is `int`or not.

if input is not `int` loop until the user enters `int`.

For instance:

```
num = input("Enter an integer:")
if not isinstance(num, int):
    while not isinstance(num, int):
        try:
            num = int(input('You must enter integer only'))
        except ValueError as ve:
            pass
```

Out:

```
Enter an integer:e
You must enter integer onlyr
You must enter integer onlye
You must enter integer only4

Process finished with exit code 0
```